# Pegar Value de input number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `input` do tipo `number`, e gostaria que o mesmo aceitasse apenas números inteiros.

Daí estou criando uma função que limita o número de caracteres e substitua o digito que não seja número com replace.

O problema, que este tipo de input aceita alguns caracteres como: `"e+.,-"`. Mas quando tento pegar o valor, ele vem vazio quando digitado algo que não seja número. Assim não consigo substituir os caracteres.

```
$("[type=number]").val();
```

Independente que existam outras formas de fazer isso, bloqueando tecla, usando input text etc. A minha dúvida é:

Existe alguma forma de pegar o value que esta digitado no campo `INPUT NUMBER`, ao invés desse valor em branco quando digitado caracteres que não sejam números?

Comment: Justamente por isso, o própio html faz a filtragem do valor. Quando você envia os dados ele envia os dados com caractere especial?

Comment: @GlenysMitchell Quando aciono o evento keyup, ele retorna uma variável vazia " " ... Qualquer carácter que não seja número, retorna vazio. Daí não é possível substituir. Há alguns dias li algo sobre value default... mas não recordo da diferença, e se sana minha dúvida.

Comment: Já tentou resgatar (mesmo vazio) e reescrever o campo?

Comment: Você fala armazenar em uma variável o valor anterior? e se vier em vazio, volto com o valor anterior?

Comment: Isso, assim se ele digitar um caracter especial quando retornar o valor vazio vai apagar o caracter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é uma limitação do próprio input. Caso digite um valor que pode ser considerado número ex.: `123e12` o `$("[type=number]").val();` vai retornar o valor certinho. Caso for digitado um numero "absurdo" ex.: `123e123456` o browser vai ignorar esse valor, pois não pode ser convertido para Number. segue alguns exemplos:

```js
console.log( Number('123') ) //numero valido
console.log( Number('123e12') ) //numero valido
console.log( Number('123e12345') ) //numero invalido
```

O mesmo vale para caso tente declarar o input com esses números:

```html
<input type='number' value='123'/> <br />
<input type='number' value='123e12'/> <br />
<input type='number' value='123e12345'/>
```

sendo assim ao digitar um numero inválido não vai ser possível ler o valor do campo

Comment: Não é possível pegar o valor do input, pois sempre retorna vazio. Só digitar "e+.,-" ele retorna vazio. A melhor opção para sanar, foi liberar apenas as teclas de números, daí nunca retorna vazio no keypress...

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer limpar os caracteres especial, sabendo que por padrão o js não vai aceitar os mesmo neste tipo de campo, aproveite o evento keydown que já fez para ir devolvendo o valor limpo.

Neste exemplo eu fiz com blur (ao sair do campo):

```
$("#numeros").blur(function(){
    const valor = $("#numeros").val();
    $("#numeros").val(valor);
});
```

Acredito que haja outras formas de fazer, talvez até com mascaras e pregs. Mas isso deve ajudar.